# Install specific version of nodejs on RHEL server

Tags: node.js, nodes

I am trying to install NodeJS 6.9.5 version at my RHEL server but it is not working.

I ran below command successfully

curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -

But yum install -y nodejs:6.9.5 command is failing with below error. Could someone guide me?

yum install -y nodejs:6.9.5
Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No package nodejs:6.9.5 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md) to install specific version of node.js.

To install node 6.9.5 in your machine,

- Install nvm `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash`
- First source your .bash_profile `source ~/.bash_profile`
- Now install your desired version `nvm install v6.9.5`

You can go through this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server), for details, especially **Install Node Using the Node Version Manager** section.

Comment: Pleasure to help you.

Comment: Hi. Everybody knows about NVM, so initially I was not going to upvote answer. I think that's why someone downvoted the question.  Then I noticed  a small link to useful article about `wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.30/node-v0.10.30-linux-x64.tar.gz && sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xzvf node-v* -C /usr/local` and this stuff was really useful, so I upvoted both question and answer. Cause it is real pain in the ass to use source ~/.bashrc for each node usage for non interactive commands on CentOs or for dockerfiles creation.